# Advice on securing WebAPI (MVC5) *without* user accounts?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC5 application - I've been historically a webforms guy, and most recently a core 2.0 guy, but never MVC5. In my core application I had used a token that was passed in the request header and validated against a value in the app.config (or stored on azure as a setting) that allowed the API request to go through.

All the examples I've found for MVC API authentication deal with user/password type situations.

What I'm looking for is the code pattern for if we have "clients" in a database - each client has a "clientID" which is for example, a GUID, then we'd generate each client an API token that they'd pass along with their client ID, and we'd validate that and allow them access to call the API.

Currently when the customer connects to the API right now, their client ID is just validated as "yes, it exists", and there's no security on the API.

It seems some variation of this code:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-rest-web-api-authorization/

Would get me close to what I'm looking to do (they seem to focus on the API token approach vs identity)

But I wouldn't mind any other thoughts or resources.

Comment: This is pretty much what JWT is all about

Comment: A custom authentication filter would be the way to go if you have your own logic: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters. You can set a custom principal (identifying the user, their roles, any other info/claims you need) here.

Comment: @NatWallbank - Does this still apply if there's no "users" per se, and simply just verifying that the client/customer has a valid API token? No roles, etc.

Comment: If you write your own authentication filter then you can ensure the token is valid, and set anything you like in the principal. So, yes, you could do that if there are no users per se.

Comment: @mdrussell0779 Sure, you have ultimate flexibility to authenticate requests however you like. You just likely won't need all of the granular role/claim verification (authorization filters) at the moment. But maybe one day you will!